# Does Thread.Yield will let the CPU do context switch to other thread in the same process or same processor?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I see the following in Joseph Albahari's Threading book (http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

> Thread.Sleep(0) relinquishes the thread’s current time slice
>   immediately, voluntarily handing over the CPU to other threads.
>   Framework 4.0’s new Thread.Yield() method does the same thing — except
>   that it relinquishes only to threads running on the same processor.

Is the context switch happen to some other thread within the same process or among the threads  that are waiting to get CPU?

If the answer is the latter, is there any way to do context switch to some other thread that is in wait state in the same process?

I understand that the thread scheduling has been taken care by the operating system. But, got struck with a problem because of Thread.Sleep(0) and trying to find the solution for it.

Editing for more clarity about the problem:

The software has two threads (say A and B) and A will wait for a signal from B for 20 milliseconds and proceed regardless of the signal. A sets the signal and to let the processor continue with B, Thread.Sleep(0) applied as the software is a time critical application where every second maters. For a second both A and B didn't continued and restored (known with the help of the logs). We thought some other process in the same processor got the CPU time slice and now looking for alternatives.

Comment: You may get more useful answers if in addition to what you think good approach to solve your problem is you also post what actual problem you trying to solve... [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: trouble with `...Sleep(0)` is an indication for structural problems with the design. Provide code snippets showing the core "trouble".

Comment: _a time critical application where every second maters_ Did you mean millisecond or microsecond maybe? Either way, `Sleep(0)` is the road to low/buggy performance.

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread.Yield` method will switch to any thread which is ready to run on the current processor.  It doesn't make any distinction about which process that `Thread` exists in

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to yield to another thread in the same process, even by P/Invoke. Windows simply doesn't support it.

An alternative would be to use some kind of co-operative multitasking, such as TPL and async/await. When you `await` something, such as the awaitable object returned by `Task.Yield()`, it enables another task queued with the scheduler to start up. It's also quite a bit more efficient than using `Thread.Yield()`, but if you're not using it yet this will likely require a large overhaul of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Yield() will just allow the scheduler to choose another thread within the same process that is ready to run, and resume it at whatever point it was stopped.  It has nothing to do with time-slicing among *processes*, which is a completely different thing.  (And rarely of concern unless you're programming the other process(es) as well.)

Note that the Yield() may have no effect at all, if the current thread is the only one able to run.  It will just return (relatively immediately) from the Yield() call.

Your question about "context switching to another thread in the same process" is a bit mis-guided.  You shouldn't think in those terms.  If you need to wait for another thread to *finish*, use Join.  If you need to signal to another thread that it should stop waiting and do something, there are a variety of mechanisms to use for that.

In short, your problem will get worse if you're trying to "outguess" the thread scheduler.

Perhaps you should be more explicit about the problem you're actually having.

Comment: "choose another thread within the same process" - please provide a link that proves that statement... This is not true to my knowledge (thread scheduling does not care about processes).

Comment: Alexei, I was just trying to describe how to think of the threading model when dealing with multi-threading within an app.  That the operating system may use Thread.Yield as an opportunity to do a process switch is of no concern to this programmer.  (And certainly needn'

Comment: 't ever be _relied on_ in any way.)

I'm just trying to get him away from Sleep(0)/Yield, as they likely won't solve his problem.

Comment: Please consider wording your post in such a way that it is clear what is indeed fact and what is "you can think of it as...". Since you did not do that your post directly contradicts to MSDN/text in the question and thus confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Thread is a wrapper around the OS threads. Due to this scheduling of Threads is performed by OS kernel and Yield just a way to tell the kernel, that you want relinquish CPU but still stay runnable (unblocked). A kernel will consider your request as a good point to perform a rescheduling and give the CPU to some other waiting thread. OS is free to give CPU to any waiting thread from the runqueue disregard the process to which it belong. There is no way to affect to the scheduler decision unless it is your own scheduler and you use so called green threads and cooperative multitasking.

In regard to your problem: you need to use explicit synchronization if you want to achieve guaranteed results. 
Yielding is a wrong way because it doesn't provide any guaranties to you. 
There are a bunch of issues that can appear from its use. 
For example, your thread B can simply have not enough time to accomplish its work and to send signal to A before A will be scheduled again, A can be scheduled immediately after Yield onto another CPU core, A even can be rescheduled again before the B will got a chance to be executed. Finally, other application can take a CPU. If you really care about time then raise priorities of both threads, but synchronize them explicitly.